# Xamarin, Cannot convert fragment to V4.App.Fragment

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm a new when it comes to Xamarin and I've ran into an issue that i could not resolve no matter what i tried
That's the error message I've been getting "cannot implicitly convert type 'Fragment1' to 'andriod.support.V4.App.Fragment

This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    int count = 1;
    PagerSlidingTabStrip _tabs;
    ViewPager _pager;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        _pager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.pager);
        _tabs = FindViewById<PagerSlidingTabStrip>(Resource.Id.tabs);
        _pager.PageMargin = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, 4, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
        _pager.CurrentItem = 0;

        string[] titles = new string[]
            {
                "Fragment1",
                "Fragment2"
            };

        var adapter = new PagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, titles);
        _pager.Adapter = adapter;
        _pager.OffscreenPageLimit = titles.Length;
        _tabs.SetViewPager(_pager);
    }
}
```

this is my pagerAdapter Code

```
public class PagerAdapter:FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private string[] Titles;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, string[] titles)
        : base(fm)
    {
        Titles = titles;
    }

    public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
    {

        return new Java.Lang.String(Titles[position]);
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return Titles.Length; }
    }

    public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return new Fragment1();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment2();
            case 2:
            default:
                return new Fragment1();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my fragment

```
public class Fragment1 : Fragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment1Layout, null);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Xamarin, but I have been dealing with fragments a lot recently and have run into this issue several times. I found that sometimes when I'm initializing the Fragments, it was using `android.app.Fragment` instead of using the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

So, wherever you initialize your Fragment(again not familiar with Xamarin), make sure you use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately even that doesn't fix the issue, still thanks for your reply

Comment: Have you tried even changing it in the class declaration? Like change public class Fragment1 : Fragment to public class Fragment1 : android.support.v4.app.Fragment?

Comment: it finally worked!! much appreciated you saved me countless hours of work.

Answer (score 0):

That error means you're inheriting from `Android.App.Fragment` instead of `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`.

You can either use the solution above or you could also use this cleaner declaration `using Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;`. Place it before or after your using statements, right before the namespace declaration.